# Call function 30 times simultaneously without any different milliseconds timing in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to call function 30 times simultaneously, without any different milliseconds timing, let say there are function name:

```
orderFlashsaleProduct();
```

If i call `orderFlashsaleProduct();` function 30 times, generally we can use looping method like this:

```
for(var a = 0; a < 30; a++) {
    orderFlashsaleProduct();
}
```

But "looping method" called function in "sequential way" not "simultaneously". So if we pay attention about timing in milliseconds, there are different timing between call function process.

If we create looping console.log milliseconds of current time it will look like this:

```
for(var a = 0; a < 30; a++) {
    console.log(new Date().getMilliseconds());
}
```

And printed console.log milliseconds value will look like this:

```
418
418
418
419
419
419
419
420
420
420
420
420
...
```

As we can see, there are different milliseconds timing when looping start and when looping the end. I need more speed timing when called function 30 times.

At least, when we called function 30 times, i want that execute simultaneously in same milliseconds. Let say, when we start called function 30 times at milliseconds **418**, then all called at milliseconds **418**. **No different timing**.

***I'm not talking about hundreds or thousands times called function in simulataneosly. I know, that's impossible. Just 30 or 20 or 10 times but in the perfect timing so it will be the real "simultaneously".***

Is there any way?

Comment: You need a faster machine ..?

Comment: @AD7six I want create bot flashsale product from e-commerce. I already get the scrapping API to the e-commerce server.. But I need more speed to execute my request API script, so my script can fight to get product flashsale with other bot player :D

Comment: Since JavaScript is single threaded and asynchronous. it will not start all the function calls at once.

Comment: @Teemu :D Maybe need some optimizing script, in this case i need perfect timing when execute function 30 times.

Comment: Even if you emit all http requests at exactly the same time - they won’t be received at exactly the same time… this question is an example of an [xy problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - what you are asking will not really help.

Comment: @AD7six It's okay about timing of HTTP request response. I just want to improve opportunity of this flashsale battle. At least my script already send http request to e-commerce server in the best speed method.. In this case.. Call 30 times request function in the perfect timing.

Comment: Besides getting a faster computer and a faster network connection, use multiple child processes or WorkerThreads in order to run through more requests in less time.  FYI, there is no "real simultaneously".  No matter how many processes or threads you use, these outgoing requests are going to be serialized on your network connection.